# download pdf from external url with error 403

Tags: node.js, http, pdf, meteor, download

Hello I'm trying to download this pdf `http://www.inema.ba.gov.br/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/Boletim-N21-Balneabilidade-para-Salvador-emitido-em-26-05-2017-1.pdf`

and I can easily do it with node.js (Meteor actually, but it's pretty similar)
the problem is I get it using a `http.get`, but every week they change the filename and my `http.get` breaks!

I want to know if I can make a request to half of the address (`http://www.inema.ba.gov.br/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/`) and still be able to get that file even if it changes every week.
Is there any way to do this?